# LaraAdmin to create many to many relationships / modules?

Tags: laravel, crud, laraadmin

We are using [LaraAdmin](http://www.laraadmin.com/) for the data modeling and CRUD of our site. It seems pretty versatile with one to many relationships such as state > city, but we don't know how to implement many to many relationships with the modules.

For example, we need to create a `teachers` module and a `students` module. Apparently, any teacher can have multiple students and any student can have multiple teachers.

**What's the supposed way to do this in LaraAdmin modules?**

Another issue is, LaraAdmin seems to be saving all relationship IDs in **JSON**. With a large number of rows in the database table, won't this be disastrous performance wise? Because, you know, one has to read all the rows for the JSON and then find a particular ID in one of the JSON(s).

**How can I make LaraAdmin to use native integer IDs in the referencing columns?**

Comment: @datsan.io,You found any solution against this ?